# How to vertically align center based on the height of a div two levels up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am wondering if you can take the height of one div and use that to position elements two levels down from it (a child of a child).

I am using Bootstrap and have tried using `position: absolute` to handle this but it doesn't work. There is also a problem I ran into simply using this:

```
.prod-pod {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(+50%);
}
```

The thing is, there are two elements using `.prod-pod` and they are different heights, with one having an additional element inside it's `col` (the one on the left). This makes the one on the left not centered vertically.

```
<div class="prod-align">
  <div class="col-md-4">

    <%= link_to "Back to products", packs_path, class: "btn btn-info btn-block top-drop" %> <!-- I don't want this thing centered vertically -->

    <div class="wellington top-drop prod-pod">
      <h3 class="featurette-heading pack-name center"><%= @pack.title %></h3>
      <h4 class="text-muted align-left">License:</h4>
      <h4 class="featurette-heading align-right"><%= link_to "EULA", legal_path %></h4>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <h4 class="text-muted align-left">Category:</h4>
      <h4 class="featurette-heading align-right"><%= @pack.pack_type %></h4>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <h4 class="text-muted align-left">Price:</h4>
      <h4 class="featurette-heading align-right">$ <%= @pack.price %> <span class="text-muted CAD">USD</span></h4>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="btn-buy" type="button">Purchase This Library</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- This is the tallest element inside .prod-align -->
    <div class="wellington top-drop">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="wellington top-drop prod-pod">
      <h3 class="featurette-heading pack-name center">What's inside</h3>
      <div class="pack-contents"><%= raw @pack.pack_contents %></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is having both `.prod-pod` divs centered vertically in the `.prod-align` div.

I am using floats inside one of the divs as well.

Comment: could you  provide an example of HTML with content (you can use lorem text and fake img ) that shows your issue and failure . I understand you use booststrap 3 , is 4 not an option (where flex is used) ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omEwgM (absolute/relative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the parent div to a flexbox using `display:flex` and the child elements should have an equal height. Now just use the `align-items` property to vertically center the child elements' content.

---

Check this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/1qzk05p4/20/)** or run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```css
@media (min-width: 992px){ /* only apply if "col-md-" and above */
  .prod-align {
    display:flex; align-items:center;
  }
}
.col-md-4 {border: #222 solid 5px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="prod-align">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="wellington top-drop prod-pod">
      <p>short height elements here</p><p>short height elements here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4"> <!-- This is the tallest element inside .prod-align -->
    <div class="wellington top-drop">
      <p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p><p>long height elements here</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="wellington top-drop prod-pod">
      <p>medium height elements here</p><p>medium height elements here</p><p>medium height elements here</p><p>medium height elements here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait, is flexbox built-in to CSS or is it a framework?

Comment: I didn't mean the content inside the `.prod-pod`, sorry. I updated my question at the bottom.

Comment: @Jake Just remove the `display:flex` property from your inner elements and only change your parent element to a flexbox. Now just add the `align-items` property to the parent element instead of the child elements. Check the updated answer and the jsFiddle.

Comment: Sweet, it works for the most part. The only problem now is that it also centered the "Back to products" link which I want to have remained at the top of the `col`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly? That would mean the div is not centered vertically anymore since you want it to begin at the top and stop halfway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188129/discussion-between-andrewl64-and-jake).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I just had to make the button above the div on the left have `position: absolute;` with some additional positioning in the `@media` element for it to remain at the top, without interfering with the div's position below it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;`.

Irrespective of the parent height, the div contents will be vertically centered.

```css
.prod-pod {

  border: 1px solid grey;
  align-items: center; 
  display: flex;
}
.height-100{
  height: 100px;
}

.height-200{
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row prod-align">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-4">

    <div class="wellington top-drop prod-pod height-100">
qqq
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="wellington top-drop prod-pod height-100">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
    <div class="height-200 wellington top-drop prod-pod">
qqqqqqq000
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To center a element in a div with CSS, you need this option :

```
align-content: center;
```

Place it on "**col-md-4**".

But I recommend you use Bootstrap 4. It's VERY easy to make your effect with this version : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/

I hope it will help you.